# Why use sigma/sqrt(n) and not sigma^2/n?

Tags: confidence-interval, central-limit-theorem

My stats book says that according to CLT and if n is large, the distribution of means of random samples is approximately normal with mean = miu and variance = sigma^2/n, where sigma^2 is the variance of the population. Then it proceeds to calculate the confidence intervals where instead of sigma^2/n, sigma/sqrt(n) is used. Are the two equivalent? If, say, sigma=4 and n=6, then:

(4^2)/6 = 4/sqrt(6)

8/6=4/2.45

This clearly isn't the same. I must be making some fundamental mistake here, please help me to find it!

Comment: Think of how the confidence interval is derived; it involves $\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$, the standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

We know, that
$$
Var_{\sigma} [\bar{X}]=\sigma^2/n
$$
So standard deviation is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$. Using aproximation by normal distribution,we know that with probability $1-\alpha$,    $\bar{X}$ takes value in interval $[\mu-z_{1-\alpha/2}*\sigma/\sqrt{n},\mu+z_{1-\alpha/2}*\sigma/\sqrt{n}]$, where $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is appropriate quatille. So
$$
\mathbb{P}_{\mu,\sigma}(\{\mu-z_{1-\alpha/2}*\sigma/\sqrt{n}\leq\bar{X}\leq\mu-z_{1-\alpha/2}*\sigma/\sqrt{n}\})=1-\alpha
$$
Some algebra inside brackets, and u will have asymptotic, $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\mu$ in the shape of $[\bar{X}-z_{1-\alpha/2}*\sigma/\sqrt{n},\bar{X}+z_{1-\alpha/2}*\sigma/\sqrt{n}]$, what means that with probability $1-\alpha$ this random interval covers true mean.